# pyplot.contourf() returns error when specified levels argument

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror, contourf

**EDIT: The issue is most likely about the version. The `levels` argument takes an integer argument in version 3.0.0, while this issue has occurred while using version 2.2.2.**

**UPDATE: The issue didn't occur after installing the version >=3.0.0.**

I'm trying to make a contour plot in Python using the `matplotlib.pyplot.contourf()` function, and it works perfectly like this:

```
plt.contourf(x, y, z)
```

but when I try to specify an integer for the levels argument, like this:

```
plt.contourf(x, y, z, levels=100)
```

it always returns the error: `TypeError: len() of unsized object`

In the documentation, it says that the argument `levels` can be either `int` or `array_like` so I don't know why it would even call the `len()` function

Any ideas why this happens and any suggestion on how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, this happens to you. The documentation changed in version 2.2.3 without this feature being fully implemented. So depending on the version of matplotlib the `levels` argument is interpreted differently.

**matplotlib < 3.0.0**

`levels` is interpreted as a list of levels where to draw contours. An integer is interpreted as a single level. For a `contourf` (a filled contour) plot you need at least two levels. Use the previously known way to specfify the number of levels as the second or fourth unnamed argument

```
plt.contourf(z, 100)
plt.contourf(x, y, z, 100)
```

**matplotlib >= 3.0.0**

`levels` can take either a list or an integer. When an integer, it signifies the (approximate [[*](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12729)]) number of levels. The relevant PR is [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/11917).

```
plt.contourf(z, levels=100)
plt.contourf(x, y, z, levels=100)
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the case, but perhaps I have a version older than 3.0.0.

Comment: I checked. That's indeed the issue (I was running version 2.2.2).